# (P ⊕ Q) ⊕ P ≡ P , Failing to show equivalence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I've been asked to show that:
$(P ⊕ Q) ⊕ P ≡ P$

with
$$ P ⊕ Q ≡ (P \land \neg Q)\lor(\neg P\land Q)$$
and Logical equivalences, how ever I failed every time I tried, any direction?

Thanks

edit:
Sorry had a little typo, meant $(P ⊕ Q) ⊕ Q ≡ P$

thanks for answers !

Comment: Does $\oplus$ indicate the standard or?

Comment: Ah, a little typo ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I am not surprised that you cannot prove it, since that 'equivalence' just doesn't hold!

That $\oplus$ is the XOR, and it has the properties of being commutative and associative, as well as:

$$P \oplus P \equiv \bot$$

and

$$P \oplus \bot \equiv P$$

As such:

$$(P \oplus Q) \oplus P \equiv (Q \oplus P) \oplus P \equiv Q \oplus (P \oplus P) \equiv Q \oplus \bot \equiv Q$$

So, your statement is equivalent to $Q$, rather than $P$!

EDIT

After fixing the typo ...

$$(P \oplus Q) \oplus Q \equiv \text{ (Definition } \oplus \text{)}$$

$$(((P \land \neg Q) \lor (\neg P\land Q)) \land \neg Q) \lor (\neg ((P \land \neg Q) \lor (\neg P\land Q)) \land Q) \equiv \text{ (DeMorgan)}$$

$$(((P \land \neg Q) \lor (\neg P\land Q)) \land \neg Q) \lor (\neg (P \land \neg Q) \land \neg (\neg P\land Q) \land Q) \equiv \text{ (DeMorgan x 2)}$$

$$(((P \land \neg Q) \lor (\neg P\land Q)) \land \neg Q) \lor ((\neg P \lor Q) \land (P \lor \neg Q) \land Q) \equiv \text{ (Absorption)}$$

$$(((P \land \neg Q) \lor (\neg P\land Q)) \land \neg Q) \lor ((P \lor \neg Q) \land Q) \equiv \text{ (Reduction)}$$

$$(((P \land \neg Q) \lor (\neg P\land Q)) \land \neg Q) \lor (P \land Q) \equiv \text{ (Distribution)}$$

$$(P \land \neg Q \land \neg Q) \lor (\neg P\land Q \land \neg Q) \lor (P \land Q) \equiv \text{ (Idempotence, Complement)}$$

$$(P \land \neg Q ) \lor (\neg P\land \bot) \lor (P \land Q) \equiv \text{ (Annihilation)}$$

$$(P \land \neg Q ) \lor \bot \lor (P \land Q) \equiv \text{ (Identity)}$$

$$(P \land \neg Q ) \lor (P \land Q) \equiv \text{ (Adjacency)}$$

$$P$$

Comment: How is the reduction in line 4 work? $(\neg P \lor Q) \land (P \lor \neg Q)$

Comment: I know that $(\neg P \lor Q) \land (P \lor \neg Q) ≡ (\neg P \land P) \lor (\neg P \land \neg Q) \lor (Q \land P ) \lor (Q \land \neg Q) ≡ (\neg P \land \neg Q) \lor (Q \land P )$ and then how to reduce more? thanks

Comment: @GDay That expression cannot be reduced further

Comment: Hi, so how $ ((\neg P \lor Q) \land (P \lor \neg Q) \land Q) $ reduced into $((P \lor \neg Q) \land Q)$ ?

Comment: @GDay That is an application of Absorption: $(\neg P \lor Q) \land Q = Q$.  And that's because $(\neg P \lor Q) \land Q = (\neg P \lor Q) \land (\bot \lor Q) = (\neg P \land \bot) \lor Q =  \bot \lor Q  =  Q$. Sorry, my notation is probably confusing here: I tend to write the principle *between* the statements, rather than after the statement I just obtained.

Comment: Oh right! I looked at it the wrong way. thanks so much

Comment: @GDay The Reduction I perform is going from $(P \lor \neg Q) \land Q$ to $P \land Q$ ... are you familiar with that principle? (not every book discusses that one)

Comment: Yes, everything is now clear to me. the Absorption was my missing piece.

Comment: @GDay Cool, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

$A\oplus A=(A\land \lnot A)\lor (\lnot A\land A)=0\lor 0=0$

$A\oplus 0=(A\land 1)\lor (\lnot A\land 0)=A\lor 0=A$

$\begin{array}{ll} A\oplus B 
&=(A\land \lnot B)\lor (\lnot A\land B)\\
&=\underbrace{(A\lor\lnot A)}_1\land(A\lor B)\land(\lnot B\lor\lnot A)\land\underbrace{(\lnot B\lor B)}_1\\
&=(A\lor B)\land(\lnot A\lor\lnot B)\\
&=(A\lor B)\land\lnot(A\land B)\qquad\text{[ an useful definition variant ]}\end{array}$

$A\oplus B=B\oplus A\quad$ immediate consequence of symmetry of above expression.

$\begin{array}{ll}(A\oplus B)\oplus C 
&=\left[\left((A\land \lnot B)\lor (\lnot A\land B)\right)\land \lnot C\right]\lor\left[\lnot\left((A\lor B)\land\lnot(A\land B)\right)\land C\right]\\
&=\left[(A\land \lnot B\land\lnot C)\lor (\lnot A\land B\land\lnot C)\right]\lor\left[((\lnot A\land \lnot B)\lor (A\land B))\land C\right]\\
&=\underbrace{(A\land \lnot B\land\lnot C)}_{\#1}\lor \underbrace{(\lnot A\land B\land\lnot C)}_{\#2}\lor\underbrace{(\lnot A\land \lnot B\land C)}_{\#3}\lor\underbrace{(A\land B\land C)}_{\#4}\\
&=\underbrace{(\lnot B\land\lnot C\land A)}_{\#3}\lor\underbrace{(B\land\lnot C\land\lnot A)}_{\#1}\lor\underbrace{(\lnot B\land C\land\lnot A)}_{\#2}\lor\underbrace{(B\land C\land A)}_{\#4}\\
&=(B\oplus C)\oplus A
\end{array}$

Now from all the demonstrated properties we get

$(P\oplus Q)\oplus P=P\oplus Q\oplus P=P\oplus P\oplus Q=0\oplus Q=Q$

---

Another idea is from the definition given, draw the truth table.
When you have $\oplus$ rule, it is straightforward to calculate $(P\oplus Q)\oplus P$.

$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
P & Q & \lnot P & \lnot Q & P\land\lnot Q & \lnot P\land Q & P\oplus Q & (P\oplus Q)\oplus P\\\hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{array}$

Last column is $Q$ so $(P\oplus Q)\oplus P=Q$